# auth0-js checkSession() does not recognise authentication made on another page with auth0-spa-js' universal login

Tags: auth0, auth0-js

I have several micro-frontend's running under the same domain, that use auth0 universal login (auth0-spa-js package) and they all work fine, recognizing each others session.

Now, I'm making a new one that requires an in-house login page with email and password, therefore it uses a different package (auth0-js) for it's Embedded login flow.

Both logins work perfectly separately, however they behave differently in these scenarios

A)

1. Login on the new microfrontend (auth0-js package), checkSession is ok
2. Go to different microfrontend that uses auth0-spa-js and checkSession is still ok

B)

1. Login on older microfrontend using universal login (auth0-spa-js)
2. Go to the new microfrontend (auth0-js package), checkSession fails with code `login_required`

Is there any way I can fix this without having both libraries auth0-spa-js and auth0-js on the new microfrontend?

Some more context:

I had 2 different applications on auth0, one for the universal flow and another one for the embedded one but now I use only one for everything and it still doesn't work.

I also have custom domains enable on auth0.´

Edit:

I've tried the solution I mentioned above - using both libraries auth0-spa-js (for silent authentication and logout) and auth0-js (for login/signup) and now it works fine with both scenarios.

For this to work I have to handle the login redirect with:

1. auth0.WebAuth.parseHash() - from auth-js
2. and then auth0.getToken() - from auth-spa-js

However this feels like an overkill and waste of resources, I should be able to have only one library.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution I mentioned above - using both libraries auth0-spa-js (for silent authentication and logout) and auth0-js (for login/signup) and now it works fine with both scenarios.

For this to work I have to handle the login redirect with:

1. auth0.WebAuth.parseHash() - from auth-js
2. and then auth0.getToken() - from auth-spa-js

However this feels like an overkill and waste of resources, I should be able to have only one library.